# Remember GPS permission state

Tags: javascript

I'm working with GPS location function and the problem is that the permission popup is coming over and over again (each new url refresh / F5 key press).

How can I remember the state that the user has chosen in his browser (APPROVED or DECLINED).

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        dispatchResponse(requestId, position.coords);
    });
}
else {
    return "No location finding";
}
```

Would be great if someone could give me a hint.

Thx!

Comment: The user can configure this in their browser settings. In Chrome e.g. you can do it here: chrome://settings/content/location  Maybe you can display instructions the user how do they allow this permission permanently for the most common browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "remember" the permission on your side. This is by design and entirely up to the browser. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation):

> For security reasons, when a web page tries to access location information, the user is notified and asked to grant permission. Be aware that each browser has its own policies and methods for requesting this permission.